# Does Diamagnetism actually lessen G forces?

Tags: electromagnetism, newtonian-gravity, acceleration

Example: Astronauts are pinned to their seats by 3gs during takeoff. If there were a sufficiently strong diamagnetic field, would the g-forces felt by the astronauts be lessened, or would they simply be crushed between the two forces?

Another example: if a humans were on a planet with higher gravity than Earth's, would a sufficiently strong diamagnetic field lessen the amount of gravity they experience, or is the diamagnetic field only lifting them, in which case, they would be crushed between the two forces?

Comment: What do you mean by "diamagnetic field?" Diamagnetism is a property of some materials, characterising how they respond to an external magnetic field.

Comment: As in diamagnetic levitation